# NSMutableArray not responding to NSArray category

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, categories

I'm experiencing something really strange: I have a `NSArray` category (with some methods I wrote) and, since `NSMutableArray` is a `NSArray` subclass, I expected it to react to the same messages I can send to a `NSArray` (so including custom methods in my category), but I discovered that `NSMutableArray` just does nothing if I send to it messages of a `NSArray` category. I get no compilation errors, of course, but nothing happens at runtime.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Even `NSMutableArray` should respond to the `NSArray` categories. Have you included (imported) the category in the class?

Comment: Yes, I did...   :(
I'll investigate deeper. Thanks a lot!